# How to express $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{2^i}$ using only simple arithmetic

Tags: summation

That simple arithmetic being only addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and exponentials.
I can simplify it using factorial, which is only multiplication, but I don't think I should. I think there's a better way but I'm just stuck in the mindset of using factorial. 
Again, the expression is $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{2^i}$

Comment: Please provide details of how you tried to do it using factorials.

Answer (score 4):

Let

$$S=\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{2^i}.$$

then

$$2S=2+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2^i}$$

$$=2+(S-\frac{1}{2^n})$$

thus

$$S=2-\frac{1}{2^n}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$S=1+\frac12+\frac14+\dots+\frac1{2^n}$$

$$\begin{align}2S=&\ 2+1+\frac12+\frac14+\dots+\frac1{2^{n-1}}\\=&\ 2+1+\frac12+\frac14+\dots+\frac1{2^{n-1}}+\left(\frac1{2^n}-\frac1{2^n}\right)\\=&\ 2+\left(1+\frac12+\frac14+\dots+\frac1{2^{n-1}}+\frac1{2^n}\right)-\frac1{2^n}\\2S=&\ 2+S-\frac1{2^n}\\-S\quad&\ \ \ -S\\\hline S=&\ 2-\frac1{2^n}\end{align}$$

> $$S=2-\frac1{2^n}$$